# (Solved) How to setup aodh and heat to auto scale in openstack victoria based on cpu usage?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

As the metric cpu_util is now deprecated, how can someone use heat to auto scale up and down using cpu usage of the instance?

Any insight is appreciated.

Edited:
We used to have transformers that did the calculation and generated cpu_util but as from stein release the transformers section has been completely removed so what it the way to get cpu_util metric and use it in heat template to scale up and scale down the instances based on cpu usage.

**gnocchi aggregates command only give the cpu usage in %age but we cannot use it in heat template.

**Solution:**

the cpu_util in percentage can be calculated using the gnocchi aggregates command.

1. Then we need to create a metric named cpu_util or cpu_usage against each resource type instance.
2. Use gnocchi aggregates command for each resource type instance ID to get the cpu_util in percentage unit.
3. Use gnocchi measures add --resource-id  -m timestamp@value metric name command to add the measure to the metric.
4. Lastly use the metric to deploy heat template when there is high cpu usage.

Convert the above process to a bash script and run a cronjob to collect the measures automatically.